# Attach Flyout control to Rectange

Tags: xaml

I am just wondering if it is possible to add Flyout control to Rectangle?
I need to display flyout control when the user is tapping the Rectangle.

Something like:

```
 <Canvas Grid.Column="0" Background="Yellow">
   <Rectangle Fill="Blue" Width="400" Height="400" Tapped="Rectangle_Tapped">                                   

      <Flyout>
         <TextBox>Some text</TextBox>
      </Flyout>
   </Rectangle>
 </Canvas>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

from the msdn documentation: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.flyout.aspx

To associate a Flyout with other controls (other than button), use the FlyoutBase.AttachedFlyout attached property

```
<Rectangle x:Name="Rect1" Tapped="Rectangle_Tapped">      
  <FlyoutBase.AttachedFlyout>
     <Flyout>
        <TextBox>Some text</TextBox>
     </Flyout>
  </FlyoutBase.AttachedFlyout>
</Rectangle>
```

and use FlyoutBase.ShowAttachedFlyout to show the attached flayout:

```
private void Rectangle_Tapped(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   FlyoutBase.ShowAttachedFlyout(Rect1);
}
```

but, I recommend you to use button instead rectangle. Rather modify template of the button to look like needed, because button provides you with other features, like visual feedback when user click on the button, focus, tabstop, etc.

Comment: Thanks.  One additional question.  I need to display this flyout at specific location.  In the case of Button I can use ShowAt() method.  But this I don't have the instance of Flyout class and can not call this method. Is there are way to display this Flyout at specific location?

Comment: to get instance of the flyout you can use FlyoutBase.GetAttachedFlyout method